# Как создавать файлы при помощи питона (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Как создавать файлы при помощи питона.

Comment: `open('filename.txt', 'w+')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('filedata')
```